# ng packager - .metadata.json file not generated in Angular 10

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I have upgraded my angular project version 8 to 10; When i execute ng serve , ng build, ng test all executes as expected and output looks fine. But im trying to export the project as tarball using ng-packagr.  It  also provides the expected output as tarball. But metadata.json file is missed in Version 10(in angular v8, it has) . The point here is, Is metadata.json is exported in another way in Angular 10? i dont think so . But need advise from experts;

Also when i import few modules from this project to another one, im getting

"Error in UnExpected Value 'Module in Library/X.module.d.ts' imported by destinationProject/Module.ts" . Please add @NgModule Annotation.

Please help

Comment: Finally, :)

this Ivy made my day difficult ; ng Packagr ts config should be updated with required attributes; in my case enable IVY should be false

Comment: I found that building by running `ng-packagr` rather than `ng build` caused the .metadata.json file to be created.